# Is it possible to collect the responses from a Google form into different worksheets based on the specific response to one of the queries?

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, worksheet

I am trying to create a Google form that collects the details of all old students in my department. But I want them stored separately according to their various year groups. Eg. All those who were admitted in 2016 should be in one worksheet, those admitted in 2017 in another worksheet and so on.
I have tried using Google Appscript but I don't know the right code to use since I'm new to Google Appscript. I'd be glad to have a block of code that helps me do this easily. Thank you.

Comment: You want to make a editable replica of those response in different sheet based on query or you just want to get filtered data from Form Response sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Sure that works, but if you want people to do work for you, then fiver is the way to go. Show what you have done and we'll help you grow your capacity to solve these challenges.

Here are some pieces of the solution.

1. You need a trigger to run, when a form is submitted and its response saved to a spreadsheet. See here for [how to create a Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#google_apps_triggers), use the manual version.
2. Make sure you read and understand this article on when a Form response is submitted, [Sheets Event -
   FormSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)
3. I suggest you save all the responses to one Sheet by default. Then, you copy the students to other Sheets within the same Spreadsheet. So your Spreadsheet contains the Sheets [2016], [2017], etc…
4. Now you should be ready to approach a solution which could look like this.

```
function copyResponseToRelevantYearSheet(e){
   // Assuming there is question in the form title 'Year of Admission' which captures the year
   const admissionYear = e.namedValues["Year of Admission"][0]
   const nameOfStudent = e.namedValues["Student Name"][0]

    // Assuming there is a Sheet called 2017
   const admissionYearSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(admissionYear)
 
   admissionYearSheet.appendRow( [nameOfStudent] )
}
```

There are also some helpful guides which are somewhat relevant here: [GAS - Samples](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/equipment-requests)